# How to get contact name, phone number, email details using Loaders

Tags: android, database, android-contacts, loader

we can get contact name and phone number using this uri

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI
```

and we can get email address using uri

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI
```

but, how can i pass these both uri's to loader and retuen Cursor loader as in code. in this code i'm returning only name and number but how can i get email to get that how can i pass

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI
```

to it

```
return new CursorLoader(this,
                 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                null,
                null,
                null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `CommonDataKinds.Phone` and `CommonDataKinds.Email` are actually part of a large table [`ContactsContract.Data`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html), that table contains lots of other info you might not be interested in, so you can select only the items that interest you (phones and emails) using [`Data.MIMETYPE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.DataColumns.html#MIMETYPE).

So the CursorLoader initialization can be something like this:

```
new CursorLoader(this,
    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
    projection,
    ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " IN (" + CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE + ", " + CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_TYPE + ")",
    null,
    null);
```

However, note that like you're getting one like per phone and not per contact when querying just on `CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI`, you'll now be getting **one row per phone or email**, and not aggregated by contact.

You should add `Data.MIMETYPE` to your projection, and use that to determine if the current row is a phone row or an email row.